# How to fetch particular value from JSON Array MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

```
 Set @a='[
      {
        "lng": "ch",    
         "zone_name": "簡體中文",
         "zone_location": "A區位置",
         "about_zone": "區域描述在這裡輸入"     
      },
      {
        "lng": "eng",    
         "zone_name": "Zone B ENG",
         "zone_location": "Zone B Location ENG",
         "about_zone": "About Zone EN"     
      },
      {
        "lng": "jp",    
         "zone_name": "ゾーン名はこちら",
         "zone_location": "ゾーンの場所はこちら",
         "about_zone": "ゾーンの説明はここに入力してください"     
      },
      {
        "lng": "es",    
         "zone_name": "Zone Locatio aquí",
         "zone_location": "Nombre de ubicación aquí",
         "about_zone": "La descripción debe ingresar aquí sobre nosotros O puede asegurarse de que no haya texto de frenado"     
      }
    ]'
```

I am storing language data in JSON format, trying to fetch name based on user's language i.e if user's preferred language is English then should return English text.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT (JSON_EXTRACT(@a,'$[3]'),'$.zone_name') ;
```

any suggest how to fetch data based on "lng" key fyi, will be using in Select query.

Comment: I'm not certain that the MySQL JSON functions can do what you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) to find a path to the users desired language e.g.

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@a, 'one', 'eng', null, '$[*].lng')
```

This will return something like `"$[1].lng"`. You can then [`JSON_UNQUOTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) that value and use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the part to the left of the `.`, i.e. `$[1]`. This can then be used as a path to [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) when concatenated with `.zone_name`:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@a, CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(@a, 'one', 'eng', null, '$[*].lng')), '.', 1), '.zone_name'))
```

Output:

```
"Zone B ENG"
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2kt2QEUhUnjoQp7Xso5fME/0)

Note the output value has double quotes around it, you may want to remove those with `JSON_UNQUOTE` to just get `Zone B ENG`.

Note also that you could use `REPLACE` to replace `.lng` in the returned path from `JSON_SEARCH` with `.zone_name`:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@a, REPLACE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(@a, 'one', 'eng', null, '$[*].lng')), '.lng', '.zone_name'))
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2kt2QEUhUnjoQp7Xso5fME/2)

If you're using MySQL 8.0+, you can use the [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function to make life *much* easier:

```
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE(@a,
                "$[*]" COLUMNS(
                  lng VARCHAR(4) PATH "$.lng",
                  zone_name VARCHAR(20) PATH "$.zone_name",
                  zone_location VARCHAR(20) PATH "$.zone_location",
                  about_zone VARCHAR(20) PATH "$.about_zone"
                  )
                ) AS j
WHERE lng = 'eng'
```

Output:

```
lng     zone_name   zone_location           about_zone
eng     Zone B ENG  Zone B Location ENG     About Zone EN
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2kt2QEUhUnjoQp7Xso5fME/3)

Comment: @Suresh btw which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0.11, do you foresee any performance issue for large data? assume my table might have 100K rows in future.

Comment: @Suresh sorry - should have asked earlier. Please see my edit with a better solution using the MySQL 8+ `JSON_TABLE` function.

Comment: i having some other fields also in select, will JSON_TABLE table still best choice? i.e. select zone_id,zone_name, lng_field1,lng_field2  from my_table ?

Comment: @Suresh if you mean outside the JSON, then it it's still good, you just need to `JOIN` the table to the `JSON_TABLE` See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119149/how-to-extract-json-array-as-table-from-mysql-text-column-when-number-of-json-ob/54145505#54145505)